# Which method of matrix determinant calculation is this?

Tags: math, matrix

This is the approach John Carmack uses to calculate the determinant of a 4x4 matrix. From my investigations i have determined that it starts out like the laplace expansion theorem but then goes on to calculate 3x3 determinants which doesn't seem to agree with any papers i've read.

```
    // 2x2 sub-determinants
    float det2_01_01 = mat[0][0] * mat[1][1] - mat[0][1] * mat[1][0];
    float det2_01_02 = mat[0][0] * mat[1][2] - mat[0][2] * mat[1][0];
    float det2_01_03 = mat[0][0] * mat[1][3] - mat[0][3] * mat[1][0];
    float det2_01_12 = mat[0][1] * mat[1][2] - mat[0][2] * mat[1][1];
    float det2_01_13 = mat[0][1] * mat[1][3] - mat[0][3] * mat[1][1];
    float det2_01_23 = mat[0][2] * mat[1][3] - mat[0][3] * mat[1][2];

    // 3x3 sub-determinants
    float det3_201_012 = mat[2][0] * det2_01_12 - mat[2][1] * det2_01_02 + mat[2][2] * det2_01_01;
    float det3_201_013 = mat[2][0] * det2_01_13 - mat[2][1] * det2_01_03 + mat[2][3] * det2_01_01;
    float det3_201_023 = mat[2][0] * det2_01_23 - mat[2][2] * det2_01_03 + mat[2][3] * det2_01_02;
    float det3_201_123 = mat[2][1] * det2_01_23 - mat[2][2] * det2_01_13 + mat[2][3] * det2_01_12;

    return ( - det3_201_123 * mat[3][0] + det3_201_023 * mat[3][1] - det3_201_013 * mat[3][2] + det3_201_012 * mat[3][3] );
```

Could someone explain to me how this approach works or point me to a good write up which uses the same approach?

**NOTE**
If it matters this matrix is row major.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be the method that involves using minors. The mathematical aspect can be found on wikipedia at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_characterizing_the_determinant

Basically you reduce the matrix to something smaller and easier to compute, and sum those results up (it involves some (-1) factors which should be described on the page i linked to).

Comment: yep - that's it.. Simple unrolled laplace expansion.

Comment: If you want more info, you should also search for "cofactor expansion"

Comment: and probably prone to roundoff errors. Pivoting usually uses some logic to avoid substracting potentially close numbers by selecting (for instance) the largest number as pivot.

Answer (score 2):

He uses the standard formula where you can compute, in pseudocode,

```
det(M) = sum(M[0, i] * det(M.minor[0, i]) * (-1)^i)
```

Here `minor[0, i]` is a matrix you obtain by crossing out `0`-th row and `i`-th column from your original matrix and `(-1)*i` stands for `i`-th power of `-1`.

The same (up to an overall sign) formula will work if you take a different row or if you make a loop over a column. If you think about how `det` is defined, it's pretty self-explanatory. Note how for 2-matrix this becomes:

```
det(M) = M[0, 0] * M[1, 1] * (+1) + M[0, 1] * M[1, 0] * (-1)
```

or, by row 1 rather then 0,

```
-det(M) = M[1, 0] * M[0, 1] * (+1) + M[1, 1] * M[0, 0] * (-1)
```

– you should recognize the standard formula for determinant of `2x2` matrix.

Similarly, for a 3-matrix composed as `N = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]` this leads to the formula

```
det(N) = a * det([[e, f], [h, i]]) - b * det([[d, f], [g, i]]) + c * det([[d, e], [g, h]])
```

which of course becomes the textbook formula

```
a*e*i + b*f*g +  c*d*h - c*e*g - a*f*h - b*d*i
```

once you expand each of `2x2` determinants.

Now if you take a 4-matrix `X`, you will see that to compute `det(X)` you need to compute determinants of 4 minors, each minor being a `3x3` matrix; but you can also expand them further so you'll have the determinants of 6 `2x2` matrices with some coefficients. You should really try it yourself similarly to what is above for `3x3` matrices.

Comment: Yep I understand it as far as the 2x2 matrix determinants are concerned but i can't see where the 3x3's are needed?

Comment: To answer your narrow question, the formula I quoted says: (1) compute `det` for some `3x3` matrices; (2) add them with coefficients.

Comment: The method is to reduce an NxN determinant calculation to the calculation of N-1xN-1 determinants, and continue until you're down to 2x2.  Therefore, the 4x4 reduces to some 3x3s, which reduce to more 2x2s.